# How do I SSH into a Windows 10 Powershell session with colors and tab completion configured from a Linux terminal?

Tags: windows, ssh, powershell

The default on Windows 10 is to ssh into cmd.exe . If you type powershell.exe from there you get highlighting and tab completion. However, it is kind of flaky and laggy sometimes. If you ssh directly into powershell it is less buggy but there is no highlighting or tab completion at all. I don't know if it is possible to setup console colors to work cross platform like this but I feel like turning on tab completion should be possible at least.

How can I get the default highlighted/tab completed experience by directly sshing into powershell?